# Group in XSLT when there are multiple values for that type of element

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I am trying to out an XML file into multiple CSV files.  Each record has this element (truncated for clarity sake)

```
<TEI>
<teiHeader>
<profileDesc>
<textClass>
<keywords>
<list>
<item>Keyword1</item>
<item>Keyword2</item>
<item>Keyword3</item>
</list>
<keywords>
</textClass>
</profileDesc>
</teiHeader>
</TEI>
```

I would like to output to different CSV files based on different item values (these are keywords for that particular record), so keyword1.csv keyword2.csv and so on.  The above would therefore appear in three different outputs.  I tried the following

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="TEI" group-by="teiHeader/profileDesc/textClass/keywords/list/item">
<xsl:result-document method="text" href="CSV Entries\Keywords\{teiHeader/profileDesc/textClass/keywords/list/item}.csv">
Article ID,Newspaper Title,Newspaper City,Newspaper Province,Newspaper Country,Year,Month,Day,Article Type,Text
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()"> 
[...output material]     
</xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

But as soon as there are two values for item in a record, it halts the process and says 'cannot write more than one result document to the same URI'

Please help.

Comment: If you use `<xsl:result-document method="text" href="CSV Entries\Keywords\{current-grouping-key()}.csv">` instead of `<xsl:result-document method="text" href="CSV Entries\Keywords\{teiHeader/profileDesc/textClass/keywords/list/item}.csv">`, does the problem go away? If not, then consider to show an input sample causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're approaching this back to front - you want one group *per distinct keyword*, and for the corresponding output file to include data from all the `TEI` elements that share that keyword, so your `for-each-group` needs to `select` the *keywords*, not the `TEI` elements:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="TEI/teiHeader/profileDesc/textClass/keywords/list/item"
                    group-by=".">
  <xsl:result-document method="text"
     href="CSV Entries\Keywords\{current-grouping-key()}.csv">
    <xsl:text>Article ID,Newspaper Title,Newspaper City,Newspaper Province,Newspaper Country,Year,Month,Day,Article Type,Text&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/ancestor::TEI[1]"> 
      [...output material]     
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Don't be misled by the `[1]` in `current-group()/ancestor::TEI[1]` - it just refers to the `ancestor::` step and is asking for the nearest `TEI` ancestor of *each* `item` in the current group.  The path `current-group()/../../../../../..` would achieve the same but IMHO the `ancestor::TEI[1]` approach makes the intention clearer.

Comment: Works great!  Thank you.  Will have to study this a bit to make sure I know what exactly I did wrong